# Splitting list in a list

Tags: python, list

```
my_list=[]
x=input('Random Word:')
my_list.append(x)
print(my_list)
```

If i input:

```
Hi,My,Name,Is,Jeff
```

The output is:

```
['Hi,My,Name,Is,Jeff']`
```

Question: How can i get the output like this`

```
['Hi','My','Name','Is','Jeff']
```

Comment: `my_list += x.split(',')`

Comment: Try `my_list=x.split(',')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `x.split(',')`

Refer documentation here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/

So your code would look like:

```
my_list=[]
x=input('Random Word:')
my_list = x.split(',')
print(my_list)
```